# Python script to search directory and find all strings that end with substring

Tags: python, string, bash, grep

I'm trying to write a Python script that searches all files in a directory and enumerates all strings that end with the substring "_updated". For example, if my files were

```
// file 1
this is an_updated example file_updated
// file 2
another file here_updated
```

I would like my script to return:

```
an_updated
file_updated
here_updated
```

I wrote the following script so far that uses `grep` to find all files that contain a string. How could I modify or extend this to get the result I want? Is `grep` even the correct approach?

```
#!/bin/bash
files=$(find docs -name "*.txt" -exec grep -l '_updated' {} \;)
```

Comment: I don't see any Python in what you posted....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from os import listdir
dirlist = list(filter(lambda x: x.endswith('_updated', listdir())))

for i in dirlist:
    print(i)
```

This will print the thing you want

Comment: actually, this will only print out the name of the file. Is there a way for me to print out the strings themselves? Such as file_updated and here_updated

Answer (score 0):

Here's the resulting script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
path = "directory"

wordSet = set()

for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(path):  
  for filename in files: 
    fname = os.path.join(dirpath,filename) 
    if fname.endswith('.txt'): 
      with open(fname,'r') as file:
        for line in file:
          words = line.split()
          for word in words:
            if word.endswith("_updated"):
              wordSet.add(word)

for word in wordSet:
  print(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` oneliner if still relevant:

```
awk '$NF~"_updated"{print $NF}' *.txt
```